# Update tensor using randomly generated column index and another tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I need a tensor with shape `[3136, 512]` where i update random value where the column is inside a list of randomly generated column index.

What i mean is that i create a tensor with all 0 and shape `[3136, 512]`, create a list with `410` elements that rappresent the column indices of the tensor created before, then i have a tensor with shape `[3136, 410]` that contain the values i want to update the first tensor. The problem is that i need to map the first value of the indices list to column 0 of the tensor update.

Example:

1. Generate 410 random columns index, done.
2. Convert them to tensor, done.
3. Update tensor_testing[row][col] with value
   initial_weight[row][colonna] where colonna is not the index of the
   initial_weights(so, it's not 0,1,2,3,4....) but associate the
   indices to the value randomly generated before.    Let's say the
   random generated the values (6,7,9) then i need to update
   tensor_testing[row][6] with value    initial_weights[row][0] and so
   on for each row until the end of the generated indices.

   ```
   import tensorflow as tf

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       import random

   # Shape of the tensors
   shape_for_layer = [3136, 512]
   subshape = [3136, 410]
   # Create a random tensor with the shape above
   initial_weight = tf.random.uniform(subshape, minval=0, maxval=None, dtype=tf.dtypes.float32, seed=None,
                                      name=None)
   # Create a 0s tensor with the shape above
   tensor_testing = tf.zeros(shape_for_layer, tf.float32)
   # Generate 410 random value for the column index where i will take the values
   layer_456_col = random.sample(range(512), 410)  # Later on set them in order
   # Convert to Tensor for tf.gather use
   indices_col = tf.convert_to_tensor(layer_456_col)


   # Result to print
   random = ...

   # Reshape back to [3136, 512] i don't know if it's really needed since it was the original shape.
   random = tf.reshape(random, shape_for_layer)

   print(tf.shape(random))
   ```

Isn't there a way to use `tf.scatter_nd` with `axis`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tf.scatter_nd`
Bellow a code with the given input shape

```
# Shape of the tensors
shape_for_layer = [3136, 512]
subshape = [3136, 410]
# Create a random tensor with the shape above
initial_weight = tf.random.uniform(subshape, minval=0, maxval=None, dtype=tf.dtypes.float32, seed=None,
                                   name=None)
# Create a 0s tensor with the shape above
tensor_testing = tf.zeros(shape_for_layer, tf.float32)
# Generate 410 random value for the column index where i will take the values
layer_456_col = random.sample(range(512), 410)  # Later on set them in order
# Convert to Tensor for tf.gather use
indices_col = tf.expand_dims(tf.convert_to_tensor(layer_456_col), 1)
final_tensor = tf.transpose(tf.scatter_nd(updates=tf.transpose(initial_weight, [1, 0]), indices=indices_col, shape=[shape_for_layer[1], shape_for_layer[0]]), [1, 0])
```

Comment: Doesn't seems to work: `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Dimensions [0,1) of indices[shape=[507,1]] must match dimensions [0,1) of updates[shape=[3136,507]] [Op:ScatterNd]`

Comment: I modified the answer accordingly, it should work now

Comment: This seems to works!